# Blinking Led with PIC18F. Debugging vs programming

Tags: led, pic

I have a `PIC18F2520` MCU. I am just trying to blink an Led with it. I have made the circuit on breadboard. I have connected 5v to VDD and VSS to gnd. I have connected led to `RC0 pin` via `330ohms` resistor. I am using internal 8mhz oscillator. I am using `c18` compiler. Following is the code I am using:

```
#include<p18f2520>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000    //8mhz oscillator
#pragma config OSC = INTIO67  //internal oscillator

void main()
{
  TRISCbits.TRISC0 = 0;
  while(1)
  {
    LATCbits.LATC0 = 1;
  }
}
```

I started the code in debug mode. So it was working, led was ON. But when I program the device, Led didnt glow. Then after few seconds led turned On. Then after few sec, it turned OFF. This keep on going. I double checked the circuit and wires. Every connection is tight and clear. But still the led was sometimes getting ON and the OFF.

Is this MCU problem. Is MCU not working properly or any other issue.

Please help

**EDIT**
I have made a small delay of 1sec and running the code in debug mode without any breakpoints. It is working as the per the code. But when I program the device, led doesnt blink and when it blink, it blinks with different frequency. Why is this happening.?

Comment: Have you disabled the watchdog?

Comment: Why do you think it is going to blink? You are writing constant high into the output...

Comment: @brhans No. I will disable it now. But how WDT is involve in this.?

Comment: WDT will reset your MCU every X period if not kicked.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I initially thought that the internal osc. is not working properly so I used the external osc. But still the problem is same. I am confused.

Comment: @Andrew How does it answer my question? You are writing `1` into the PIN, so it will always be `on` (or off - depending on your connection).

Comment: If you really want to get help, you better follow the comments and not doing random experiments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try either adding a pull-up resistor from /MCLR/VPP/RE3 to the supply or disabling MCLR.

Comment: Thankyou. I was missing this. I have added 1k resistor to the MCLR and 5v and now it is working fine.

Comment: I have done this myself more than once!

Comment: WTF? Blind leading the blind?